# Is 'show_c_source()' broken?

Tags: r, pryr

Been trying to use `show_c_source()` from Hadley Wickhams pryr package, and every time I get the following error message:

`Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection`

Even the examples provided in the function documentation do not work:

```
 > example("show_c_source")

 shw_c_> ## No test: 
 shw_c_> show_c_source(.Internal(mean(x)))
 Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

I'm running this on a 10.11.3 Mac OSX, R 3.2.4

Comment: I ran into this recently and filed an [issue](https://github.com/hadley/pryr/issues/48). No response yet...